# Setting up a vpn between two windows 2003 servers

Tags: windows, vpn

I am in Australia and we have an office in the US which has a spare pc in it, accessible via remote desktop.

I would like to set up a vpn connection between my server here in Australia and that PC (but no other pc's in the US office).

What's the best way to go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Windows Server 2000, Microsoft has a knowledge base article about the topic: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308208.

You'd just have to make a user account that no one else has the password to.

Comment: +1 for zianchoy's soloution should work pretty much word-for-word on your Windows 2003 servers. I used to use exactly this, but in the end bought a pair of Linksys RV042s as I found the above wasn't too reliable, however to be fair, I was trying to do something quite a bit more convoluted. If you are looking for something ad hoc, you could always create a VPN endpoint on the remote server (RRAS has a wizard that does this), then dial in using the VPN client built into windows from your location to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.